# Order status based on order number or email address without being logged in

Tags: netsuite

Looking for help after a lot of dead ends--there is an Order Status extension for SCA but our site is not on the version needed to use it. We would like customers to be able to check their order status by submitting their order # on our website. Is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what type of form would be used on the website to pull this information since it isn't adding any information to a customer record, but instead pulling information and displaying it.

Comment: i suppose you could setup a restlet that accepts an order number parameter and returns a status, then call this from the frontend. you would probably want it to pass through some backend step first for security.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Do you know if there are any resources available that have step by step instructions on the suggestions you made? I am not familiar with restlets. Thanks again.

Comment: I do not. You would want to work with someone who is a programmer. Documentation on creating a restlet is provided in the NetSuite documentation. Restlets can do almost anything you want in NetSuite, they do not anticipate and document the thousands of diff use cases, they just document the tool you customize to do so.